# How to find joint distribution probability from joint density?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Area $D$ is defined as the enclosed area by the points $(0,0),(2,0),(0,2),(2,8)$. Point $(X,Y)$ is chosen randomly from $D$ with uniform density. Need to calculate the joint distribution function $F_{X,Y}$ at $(1,7)$

I calculated that the density in $D$ is 0.1, and I noticed that the point is outside the area, but the answer is clearly not zero. So what to do?

Comment: Why is it not zero? $P(Y=7) = 0$ ?

Comment: By definition, $F_{X, Y}(1, 7) = \Pr\{X \leq 1, Y \leq 7\} = \int_{-\infty}^{1} \int_{-\infty}^7 f_{X, Y}(x,y) dydx$. Note that these integration limits corresponding to a lower-left quadrant of the plane when you centered at $(1, 7)$. So you just need to find out the area of the support $D$ (which is a trapezium) inside this region, multiply by the density.